# How to Fix Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, iconv, laravel-5.4

I uploaded my Laravel project to server. It displays following error. How to fix it?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() in /home/invoice/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 358

Comment: Make sure your version of php is build with the iconv extension. try running `php --ri iconv` in the terminal, which should show `iconv support => enabled`

Answer (score 3):

Did you install `iconv` PHP extension. If not please install and enable it. This may fix your problem. Please see the Documentation. Here is the [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php).

Answer (score 2):

You need to install iconv extension.

You need to make sure that **php-iconv** and **php-mbstring** are installed on the server. By default, mbstring is not installed on cPanel/WHM servers

Easiest way is `composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv`

Answer (score 1):

You need the polyfill package. You can download the polyfill package with composer or you go on [this site](https://php-download.com/package/symfony/polyfill-iconv) and download it without composer.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The given error message (which is a year old!) comes from code within that package....